# How to make use of an additional hard drive as system space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

The problem is that my computer consists of 2 hard drives a 500 GB SSD and a 2TB HDD the problem is that the 50GB partition allocated for linux on my SSD is almost full and I would like to utilize the almost 1.8 TB of free space on my HDD, how do I go about doing that? I know how to create a `ext4` partition and how to mount it but that just makes it another space of memory, how do I get my system to use it once my SSD is full? Since the partitions are on separate drives I can't really merge them right? What can/should I do? I always could backup all my files and reinstall linux mounting the HDD partition as `/home` but I'd really prefer not to do that. Would much appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: Anything in this resource you might find helpful? https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

The easiest option is to create additional filesystems on a separate HDD and mount them in the directories in your home such as:

1. /home/you/2ndhdd/Pictures
2. /home/you/2ndhdd/Backups
3. /home/you/2ndhdd/Films
4. /tmp
5. (any other place you may need)

You can use LVM to be able to resize the filesystems on the fly.

Look for "automount" if you'd like the filesystems mounted automatically when you boot the machine up.

## Solution 2

2nd solution depends how your Linux is installed - if it is using LVM, you can add new physical volume to the current volume group and than just extend current filesystems with the new space. The advantage is flexibility, but the disadvantage that the disks now depend on each other. In other words if your computer goes down and you'd like to recover data, you need to attach both disks to another machine. You cannot just use one of the HDDs to recover the data or at least it is far more difficult.

My personal preference is solution 1 unless I have 3 or more drives in a volume group to create RAID 5.

Comment: will this also add extra space to my `/tmp` folders and such because often when I need to run certain docker containers it generates a lot of data/files and eventually says that I ran out of space...

Comment: You can create a separate partition or logical volume on the extra drive and mount it over /tmp, A partition is slightly faster, but far more troublesome to resize. Logical volume is easy to resize, however adds a little overhead. Unless you really stress the machine performance difference is not noticeable. Also not sure how the second drive is connected - if it is USB (slow) I'd rather move some data to external drive and enlarge / replace internal /tmp, if it is high speed eSATA or sth like that no performance impact is likely to be visible.

Comment: I have created brief Q & A with more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219011/small-internal-drive-need-far-more-space-in-tmp-shall-i-put-it-on-external-dr