# Small internal drive, need far more space in /tmp, shall I put it on external drive or internal one?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, performance, external-hdd

I have a small internal SDD drive with Ubuntu and I often run-out of /tmp space. I am going to add another, large HDD. It is critical for me that /tmp is as fast as possible not to impact performance of my key applications. What is better from the performance point of view:
* create a partition on external drive and mount it over internal /tmp, or
* move some data to make more space in internal /tmp

Comment: Why not buy an internal storage device of adequate size, and replace the small SSD?

Comment: It has to be as fast as possible? Then you should go with a ramdisk. (`/tmp` is completly storred in the RAM. But you maybe have to upgrade your ram.

Comment: @MelcomX You're perfectly right if only the hardware would permit so large RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to first measure the performance of both drives and put /tmp on the faster one. The easiest way is for example to copy a bunch of large files first to the internal /tmp and than to the external volume.

Be sure first to erase all partitions and create new partition table and a new filesystem in the format you choose (such as ext4). Different filesystem formats tend to have differences in performance.

Than you choose faster one and mount over /tmp

To make better assessment you can also first analyse the behaviour of your key apps - whether they create one large file or a bunch of small temporary files. Than for /tmp you can choose filesystem format best suited for your case.

Answer (score 2):

To keep matters clean and tidy, consider using Stacer from the Ubuntu Software Center and use the System Cleaner option to clear down unnecessary files.

Alternatively, open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install stacer
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Graham for highly valuable input. When creating this Q&A I hoped for contributions exactly like that.

Comment: If it solves your issue, perhaps you would be kind enough to mark it as the accepted answer to make it easier for others with the same issue to find it in the future?

Comment: I still lack an app that would benchmark hard drive in several scenarios and allow creating a filesystem in central cylinders of HDD. For some reason I cannot find Stacer in software centre (Pop shop. I am using Pop os an Ubuntu 18 clone) to check for benchmarking options. Let me wait for a few days to choose the best answer.

Comment: ok, I've added repo and installed Stacer, however I cannot find any disk benchmarking section. Did I miss something?